# How to improve my MacBook Pro mid 2012 performance running macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, performance, macos-catalina

I have mid 2012 MacBook pro with (2.5 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 & 4GB ram). The system is running slow.
Have switched off few features/apps to run
1. dynamic dock
2. Sri

Any suggestions to improve performance will be really helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of things after searching over the net.

The Disk Utility >> First Aid seemed to work for me.

There was some improvement.
The chrome started opening quick and Finder response was also better